# Roo Addon Development - Not Finding Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-commons, spring-roo

I am creating an application that reads the Spring Roo Scaffolding information and generates a jquery-mobile application. I'm now trying to build it as a Roo addon but struggling with the dependency jars not getting deployed or bundled with the deployment. I generated an advanced addon template using roo. Tried to test the application in roo using

> osgi start --url
>   file:///path-to-addon-project/target/addon-bundle-name.

and i get the error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.uibinder [76]:        Unable to resolve 76.0: missing requirement [76.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=2.1.0)( !(version>=3.0.0)))
```

I believe it's not finding my dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I remove the commons-io dependency and code, everything works great.  Spent way to much time trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In roo 1.2.1 they now reference the commons-io dependencies.  No longer a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In roo 1.2.1 they now reference the commons-io dependencies.  No longer a conflict.